# AngularDart installed with Dart 2

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is AngularDart installed with Dart 2?

I can do `dart --version` but how do I know which version AngularDart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
dependencies:
  angular: "^5.0.0-alpha+13"
```

to `pubspec.yaml` and run

```
pub get
```

The output and the created `pubspec.lock` tell you the fetched package versions.

For this Angular version you need Dart 2

Answer (score 1):

> Is AngularDart installed with Dart 2?

No, AngularDart is **not** included in the Dart SDK.

[AngularDart is a separate pub package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular) that you'll include as a dependency in your Dart project's [pubspec.yaml](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec) (as explained by Günter), on a per-project basis.